# Converting raster band to .txt file using GDAL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal

How do I convert a raster band on my map in QGIS to a .txt file?

I have tried several things.

1. I have tried using the gdal2xyz function in QGIS. However, this outputs the data in a .csv format which for some reason truncates the decimal values when I try and resave it as a .txt file. The decimal values are important for my project.
2. I have tried using the translate function in QGIS which converts the map into a .xyz file which I was hoping to resave in a .txt format. However, this does not allow me to choose a specific band to convert to a .xyz file. Rather, the function only converts the first band on the map.
3. I have tried doing this in python:

   ```
   import processing
   layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('wc2.1_2.5m_bioc_BCC-CSM2-MR_ssp126_2021-2040')
   layer = layers[0]
   output = 'C:/Users/NAME/Desktop/QGISOuputs/2021BIO19NEWNEW.xyz'

    result = processing.run("gdal:translate", 
        {'INPUT': layer,
        'Band': 19,
        'TARGET_CRS':None,
        'NODATA':None,  
        'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,
        'OPTIONS':'',
        'EXTRA':'',
        'DATA_TYPE':0,
        'OUTPUT': output})

    print('Your file was created: {}'.format(result['OUTPUT']))
   ```

When I tried doing this, the output was once again the first band of the map even though I specified in the parameters that I wanted the 19th band.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/372713/edit) (not as a comment) to define what you want in the ".txt" file?  There are a number of different ways to represent raster data in a text file.

Comment: How did you come to use the 'Band' parameter? Did you find it from some tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add

```
'EXTRA' : '-b 19'
```

parameter to the input parameters in your command. Bands are counted from 1!

If you use the Processing Toolbox -> GDAL -> Translate command from the GUI of QGIS, you can see the gdal_translate command at the bottom of the window:

[image]

After running the command on the Log tab of the window you can see the input parameters what you can use from Python (on the pictures band 3 was used):

[image]